# Vue-websocket server not found

Tags: vue.js, websocket, vuejs2

So I have been having this problem for the past few days, but no luck.

I'm using the vue-websocket library found at (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-websocket)

I have followed the steps for the initial import and setup(Main.js)

```
import VueWebsocket from "vue-websocket";
Vue.use(VueWebsocket,  'ws://localhost:3002/ws')
```

But even before I began writing code, I got errors that look like this:

[Basic structure of the error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EalpL.png)

Now if I open up the "Network" tab in I get:

[Image of the network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHroC.png)

The back- end is done in .Net Core 2.0 and is using JWT to authenticate

Any AND all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question because I hope that this solution will help people that are in the same dilemma as me.

The problem lies in the library, so the answer is don't use it, as I couldn't get it to connect to the server even though the URL was correct.

Instead, use this library (**vue-native-websocket**) that can be found at:

https://github.com/nathantsoi/vue-native-websocket